# Django elasticsearch dsl completion field issue

Tags: django, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-dsl

I am trying to implement search suggestions using `django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf` for streets.

This is `documents.py`:

```
class StreetDocument(Document):
    id = fields.IntegerField()
    name_ru = StringField(
        fields={
            'raw': KeywordField(),
            'suggest': fields.CompletionField(),
        }
    )
    ... # same for name_uz and name_oz
    tags_ru = fields.CompletionField()
    ... # same for tags_uz and tags_oz

    class Django:
        model = Street
        fields = (
            'code',
            'street_type'
        )
```

in `views.py` I have this:

```
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.constants import SUGGESTER_COMPLETION
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.filter_backends import SuggesterFilterBackend, CompoundSearchFilterBackend
from django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf.viewsets import DocumentViewSet

class SuggestionListAPI(DocumentViewSet):
    document = StreetDocument
    serializer_class = StreetDocumentSerializer
    filter_backends = [
        CompoundSearchFilterBackend,
        SuggesterFilterBackend,
    ]
    search_fields = (
        'code',
        'name_ru',
        'name_uz',
        'name_oz',
        'tags_ru',
        'tags_uz',
        'tags_oz'
    )
    suggester_fields = {
        'name_ru_suggest': {
            'field': 'name_ru.suggest',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
        },
        ... # same for name_uz and name_oz
        'tags_ru': {
            'field': 'tags_ru',
            'suggesters': [
                SUGGESTER_COMPLETION,
            ],
        },
        ... # same for tags_uz and tags_oz
    }
```

Request to `/suggestions?name_ru_suggest__completion=tolstoy` does nothing, just receiving all streets unfiltered.

Request to `/suggestions?search=tolstoy` works great, but I need autocompletion.

Where did I go wrong? And that will be great if it's possible to use two fields for suggestion at once.

Thanks for your time and help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're using wrong endpoint for suggestions. Correct name is `suggest`.

Example: http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/publishers/suggest/?country_suggest__completion=Ar

[Corresponding viewsets](https://github.com/barseghyanartur/django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf/blob/master/src/django_elasticsearch_dsl_drf/viewsets.py#L44)

As of your question about using two fields for suggestion at once, it's possible to get suggestions for multiple fields at once. For instance, if you have `title` and `author`, both properly indexed and configured, you could query it as follows:

http://127.0.0.1:8000/search/books/suggest/?title_suggest=wa&author_suggest=le

This will, however, return you the following result:

```
{
    "title_suggest": [...],
    "author_suggest": [...] 
}
```

However, if you need to refine your suggestions based on some criteria, you could do that using context suggesters (search for it in the official documentation of django-elasticsearch-dsl-drf).

Comment: Thank you so much.  I've used the wrong endpoint. 
`http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/suggestions/suggest/?name_ru_suggest__completion=Ar` works great. 
And sorry, I can't make `contains` work. Tried `http://127.0.0.1:8000/ru/suggestions/?name_ru__contains=Ar`. It's not a proper URL?

Comment: `contains` is not a valid lookup for suggestions. Elasticsearch offers three types: `completion`, `term` and `phrase`. If you need partial matches, you better use ngrams. Example project does contain a couple of examples.